# Network monitoring tool

Tags: networking, monitoring

I am looking for a turnkey solution for server monitoring, especially disk space usage that notifies of certain events such as a particular drive getting low on space via email, text or both.

The client has 11 machines that need monitoring and money is not an issue with them as they run a time critical operation.

Any insights from personal experiences would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want a _network_ monitoring tool, but a _server_ or other end-device monitoring tool. Unfortunately, this is what the [help] says: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question

Comment: If these are Windows machines you need monitoring for, check out CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either Zabbix, [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) or [Pandora FMS](http://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/server-monitoring/). They're all basic monitoring solutions that can help in a greater or lesser measure heavily depending on the infrastructure and the time as you mentioned. In your position, for that small amount of devices I'd try one out that has an Open Source edition like Pandora FMS or OpenNMS.